# WireMock Standalone issue while using {{{pickRandom '1' '2' '3'}}}, {{randomInt lower=5 upper=9}}

Tags: wiremock-standalone

I am trying to use Pick random helper method for my standalone wiremocks.

I am able to use helper {{randomValue length=10 type='NUMERIC'}}

However when I try to use other helpers like {{{pickRandom '1' '2' '3'}}} or {{randomInt lower=5 upper=9}}
It starts throwing exceptions

I am trying to pick random value for a Attribute in my response body to have random value either from a range of values or from a list of values like below

"response": {
"status": 200,
"fixedDelayMilliseconds": 1000,
"body": "{"accountId": "{{{pickRandom '1' '2' '3'}}}"}",
"transformers":[
"response-template"
]

but its give cannot find helper exception while randomValue works fine.

Any inputs are most welcomes. I am using wiremock-standalone-2.26.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with standalone wiremock version 2.26.3 which was not compatible for these two methods.
After upgrading to latest version 2.32.0 working fine now.